# Query very long to execute

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am executing a *Postgresql* database on a `2GB RAM VPS`.

The settings are :

```
max_connections = 100
work_mem=1MB
shared_buffers=128MB
```

I am executing a pretty simple query with a million rows :

```
SELECT s.executionTime, g.date, s.name
FROM SimulationStatsGroup g
LEFT JOIN SimulationStats s ON s.group_id = g.id
WHERE g.name = 'general'
ORDER BY g.date DESC
```

I have 2 tables : `SimulationStatsGroup` and `SimulationStats`. `SimulationStatsGroup` contains between 1 to 13 `SimulationStats`. `SimulationStats` is a simple entity that contains numeric values like `executionTime` used by my application. Each `SimulationStatsGroup` and `SimulationStats` have a name.

Here is the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` that I get : http://explain.depesz.com/s/auLK

Why is my query so long to execute ?

Comment: On reason is the "*Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 140784kB*". Try to increas the `work_mem` for your session and check how much that improves the query. Although 2GB RAM is really small for a DB server (I think Oracle would refuse to start on that...)

Comment: You are returning over a million rows.  Why are you complaining about the execution time?  Much of that time could simply be returning the data (and the sort doesn't help).

Comment: Do you have indexes on SimulationStats(group_id) and SimulationStatsGroup(id)? As others have noted, sorting one million records is bound to take time anyway.

Comment: Are you sure the results from EXPLAIN ANALYZE came from the query above? The ORDER BY looks a bit different. An index on g.date could help to speed up the sorting

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It's still taking long time with 10MB work_mem

Comment: @Jayadevan I don't think I have indexes on these columns, how can I check that in psql ?

Comment: @FrankHeikens yes it's the same query (just aliases changed to simplify it)

Comment: Check \di and the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-psql.html

Comment: @Jayadevan Indexes work for me (a little bit for this query and 200 times better for another query that was taking too much time). Could you write an answer so that I can validate it ?

Comment: @FabienHenon - done. Added it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create  indexes on SimulationStats(group_id) and SimulationStatsGroup(id).

Comment: Thank you, It improved the execution time of this query and of other queries (with other indexes). I have a 200x less time improvement for some queries

Answer (score 0):

In the Sort (step #2) in the explain plan, it looks like the database is either lugging around unreferenced columns (not optimum) and/or sorting by them (ouch). Honestly though, I don't work on Postgres, so that is just an educated guess. The database engine may not be smart enough to discard unreferenced columns early in the process. I'd try this SQL to nudge the database engine into discarding unreferenced columns before it gets to the sort, and you may see a significant runtime improvement:

```
SELECT s.executionTime, g.date, s.name
FROM ( select id, date from SimulationStatsGroup WHERE g.name = 'general') as g
LEFT JOIN ( select s.group_id, s.name, s.executionTime from SimulationStats ) as s 
       ON s.group_id = g.id   
ORDER BY g.date DESC
```

If this version shows a runtime improvement, please run another Explain, and let us know if there are less columns list in the Sort step. If so, my hunch was likely correct. If correct, hopefully the Postgres developers will take note and try to discard unreferenced columns for us in a future version, instead of us manually coding it.